# Why 'IN' operator is removing duplicates from subquery

Tags: sql, duplicates

Duplicate reference_number exists in tableC, but the 'IN' operator is not considering duplicates i.e IN is only taking unique value.

```
select sum(cost)
from   tableA  a   left join tableB b
on a.contract= b.CONTRACT and a.code= b.code_no 
where a.ref_id in (select c.REFERENCE_NUMBER
from tableC c  join tableD d on c.reference_number=d.id
where c.year='2022'  

)
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like you want JOIN instead.

Comment: If the same ID is in the In statement more than once, the outer query will only return it the one time (since it is the same ID).  If you want duplicates change it to a join.

Comment: Thanks ,when i tried left join, the query returned more cost price than the actual

Comment: Sample data and desired results would go a long way so we don't have to backwards engineer your not-working SQL to guess why your data is causing an aggregate to balloon. I mean, we know it's a 1:many relationship, but we don't know what you want to do about that reality.

Comment: `where 1 in (1,2,3)` and `where 1 in (1,1,2,3)` and `where 1 in (1,1,1,1,1)` are all equivalent and all evaluate to `true`

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And also note that depending on type of relationship, you sometimes need to aggregate in a subquery _before_ joining.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). What does the image show anyway? One of the original tables? The query result? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

`IN` is not "removing" duplicate values.  It's ignoring them because they don't change the answer.

Suppose you have a table `A`, with a single column `a`, and a single row:

```
a
-
1
```

Now you query it:

```
select a from A where a in ( 1, 1, 2, 2 );
```

*Logically*, the query processor considers each row in `A` *once*: is the value in `a` mentioned in the `IN` list?  If yes, it's a match, else not.  The processor does not continue to consider other values in the list, because it has its answer.

For that reason, by the way, it's often counterproductive to use `DISTINCT` with `IN`:

```
select * from A where a in (select distinct a from B)
```

because the `DISTINCT` may require a sort, which, on a large table, may be more expensive than just scanning the unsorted values of `B`.  By omitting `DISTINCT`, you let the query optimizer decide if sorting is cost-effective for that particular query.